# Find the last K survivors in Josephus Problem in O(N)

Tags: c++, josephus

I want to find the last K (very small K, K < 5) survivors in the classic [Josephus Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem). I understand how only the LAST survivor can be found efficiently in O(N), but how do I work backwards to find the last K survivors?

This is the code I'm using for the problem, found on cp-algorithms.

```
int josephus(int n, int k) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
      res = (res + k) % i;
    return res + 1;
}
```

The code gives the position that would be removed. Is there a way to alter this to find the 2nd last, 3rd last and so on to be removed?
I am aware finding the exact positions can be done in O(N log N), but if I only want to find the last K, can it be reduced to O(N)?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Then please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If K<k0 for some constant k0 then repeated application of your function already falls in O(N).

Comment: And as this sounds very much like some kind of coding "competition" or "judge" problem, please note that such sites are not to be used for any kind of learning or teaching of the basics of programming or languages. That's just not their purpose. Also don't blindly copy and use code you find if you don't really understand it in great deal. That makes you part of [a cargo cult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) which doesn't help you learn anything either.

Comment: @bitmask, if I run it K times, as far as I know, there isn't a way to stop the algorithm, as it builds from down to up, and the result halfway isn't the answer required.

Comment: @Lithanium You have to skip the already selected slots, obviously. But as long as you can see K as constant, your complexity remains O(N). The code gets a bit uglier but skipping individual values is relatively cheap computation-wise.

Comment: @bitmask is there a way to work backwards, after you have obtained the result because the current code works out the position which are last removed?

Comment: @Lithanium Ooohh! I completely misunderstood your question, I think. Yes, what you want is probably trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can just log all values that you have encountered, discarding values you encountered more than k steps ago:

```
std::vector<int> josephus(int n, int k) {
    int res = 0;
    std::vector<int> ring(k); // ring buffer of size k
    std::size_t r = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
      res = (res + k) % i;
      ring[r++ % k] = res; // log all values in a ring buffer
    }
    std::vector<int> lasts(k);
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
      lasts[j] = ring[r++ % K] + 1; // extract them in order
    }
    return lasts;
}
```

Comment: But res stores the position of the person that would have been killed, but it doesn't represent the actual location in the original group.